# C++ figure out if the debugger is attached

Tags: c++, debugging, deadlock, stack-trace

I use stackwalk64 to generate stacktraces for C++ in visual studio 2008 using the latest symchk.exe and dbghlp.dll. This works fine when I'm running the standalone exe. However, when the debugger is attached I deadlock visual studio. I previously had a workaround where I downloaded all of the system32 symbols to disk and this worked well, but a recent update seems to have broken my workaround even though I updated the symbols. Ideally I would like to determine if the visual studio debugger is attached (it will only ever be the VS debugger) so I can turn off my stack traces in that case. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Use [`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms680345(VS.85).aspx) and possibly [`CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms679280(VS.85).aspx)