# How to detect whether there is a debugger attached in c++?

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-c++

I have created a macro,

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a) if (a) __asm int 3;
```

But the problem is if there is no debugger attached, the program would run incorrectly.

So I need to know whether there is a debugger attached. If there's a debugger, the app should call `int 3`. Otherwise, it should not.

How could i do this?

Comment: poosible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818628/c-figure-out-if-the-debugger-is-attached

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679280%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [`IsDebuggerPresent`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680345%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) - and no, `CheckRemoteDebuggerPresent` doesn't necessarily mean that the debugger runs on a different machine, just that there is a debugging process in the system that can deal with breakpoints etc (when using a Remote Debugger, there is a small process on the target system too, which is where it comes from).

Edit: And at this point I would DEFINITELY suggest some form of function, rather than a macro.

Comment: If I use function, the debugger would interrupted in the function, which is not what i want.

Comment: @Useless: I need to break at where i input DEBUG_BREAK, otherwise I　would rather use the breakpoint in the visual studio.

Comment: @Jichao One click on the "step" button should get you to the point where you put your DEBUG_BREAK. Unless I'm completely missing something...

Comment: @MatsPetersson: Yes shift+f11 could send me to the caller of DEBUG_BREAK, but if i use macro, the program would stop at right the caller rather that the inner of the function.

Answer (score 7):

For what you want to do, it would be better if you'd use the proper exposed `kernel32.dll` function [`DebugBreak`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679297.aspx). Basically along the lines of

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a) if(a) if (IsDebuggerPresent()) DebugBreak()
```

or instead of doing the `__asm int 3` routine, use the VC-supplied intrinsic `__debugbreak`, i.e.:

```
#define DEBUG_BREAK(a) if(a) if (IsDebuggerPresent()) __debugbreak()
```

The latter makes a difference (compared to `int 3`) when compiling with `/clr` as pointed out [in the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f408b4et.aspx). Of course the intrinsic hasn't always been there, so depends on your VS/VC version (which you don't state).

In both cases you need at least `windows.h` included for `IsDebuggerPresent()`.

---

However, that's the exact reason you would have a debug and release build and build those conditionally. Keep in mind that the optimizer can garble the results in the debugger despite your efforts to carefully place the breakpoints in code. The reason is simply that some lines in your source code won't be represented anymore or will have changed in a deterministic manner. So using one configuration for both doesn't make a lot of sense. So what I'm saying is to use something along the lines of:

```
#ifdef _DEBUG
#   define DEBUG_BREAK(a) if(a) __debugbreak()
#else
#   define DEBUG_BREAK(a) do {} while(0)
#endif
```