# __debugbreak hangs on background thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, winapi, visual-studio-2008, debugbreak

I'm trying to debug gnarly threading issue (in C++ code on Windows) that takes millions of runs to reproduce.
"printf debugging" is not giving me enough information so I'd like to break into the debugger at the first point I detect an issue.

I've been using __debugbreak() to do this, but when that is invoked on a background thread and the debugger is not already attached it hangs. While it is hung I can attach the debugger and I'll see one of the threads is blocking on that call.

This seems to be a viable workaround, but I'd like to be sure that this is the expected behaviour. I can't seem to find any reference to it while googling, which makes me suspicious that I'm overlooking something.

Anyone know the chapter and verse on this?

[update]
Actually whether I see the dialog or not seems pretty random.
Worse, just as random - but independently - the __debugbreak() does not block the thread and the process has exited before I can attach the process (whether manually or from the debug dialog)).

Comment: Maybe you can use one or both of the functions presented here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818628/c-figure-out-if-the-debugger-is-attached

Comment: Hi Mats. Thanks for the suggestion. I do, already, use IsDebuggerAttached(). Not sure how that helps here. I want to invoke the dialog that asks if I want to debug *when the debugger is not already attached*.

Comment: Sorry, I was perhaps confusing what you were asking for - I thought you didn't want it to hang when there wasn't a debugger there. So, if your question is simply "Can I expect a `__debugbreak()` to cause the thread to stop until I connect the debugger, then the answer is "Yes".

Comment: Right. Slightly more specifically: should I expect to not see that dialog if it is invoked from a background thread (although sometimes I do!)

Comment: I'm not sure about that one. I'm not entirely sure how the debug dialog box comes about.